# Whats is the interpretation of eigvectors * Covariance Matrix * eigenvetors.T? Where the eigen vectors of A.T*A.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance

I was tinkering with stock data and trying to find a new basis for correlation coefficients. I decided to multiply the eigenvectors matrix of Transpose A multiplied A, to the covariance matrix. I ended up with a symmetric matrix of really small values. What is the interpretation of this multiplication?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Nicholas Is the matrix $A^TA$ different from the covariance matrix in this case?

Comment: @Nicolas Also, are in the "eigenvectors" matrix, do the eigenvectors appear as the rows or as the columns of the matrix?